# Loading drawable from sd card

Tags: java, android, path, drawable, sd-card

I'm trying to load a png image as a drawable from my device sd card.
I use the following function but it doesn't work:

```
public Drawable getDrawable()
{
return new BitmapDrawable(imagePath);
}
```

The image path is: mnt/sdcard/MyFolder/image.png

The app crashes when I try calling that method, how should I load my png image located in my sdcard and cast it into a Drawable object?

Comment: Look at `decodeFile` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String)

Comment: @Doomsknight Can you provide an example please? I was looking now for BitmapFromFile but couldn't find any information about it.

Comment: @Doomsknight I see, so I'll have to cast afterwards the bitmap to a drawable object?

Comment: Glad it helped. Ive added an answer to help others, if you want to tick it please :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is actually a BitmapDrawable constructor straight from file path. The method you are using is depricated. Try:

```
Drawable myDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), pathName);
```

If this doesnt work, Try getting a bitmap and creating a drawable from it:

The bitmap can be created with `decodeFile`

You can use it like this:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
```

Then you can use the bitmap for drawing etc.

to convert Bitmap to drawable use

```
Drawable myDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), myBitmap);
```

Take a look [Here (Bitmaps)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String) and  [Here (Bitmap Drawables)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#BitmapDrawable%28android.content.res.Resources,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29) for more info.

Comment: The first piece of code should be = new BitmapDrawable() as it is a constructor.

Comment: @JohnJSmith Changed. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am simple do like that

```
public Drawable getDrawableFromPath(String filePath) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    //Here you can make logic for decode bitmap for ignore oom error.
    return new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
}
```