# android error setting Drawable

Tags: android, string, drawable

I have the follwing code

```
 File f = new File(temp);  
 Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(f.getAbsolutePath());
 background.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

temp is a string that contains the path of a picture on the sd card in the form "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/pic1.jpg"

I get the error "File cannot be resolved to a variable" appearing in the File part of the first line

Any idea how is fix this?

Any Help appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 1):

I think you have answer here: [Loading drawable from sd card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652798/loading-drawable-from-sd-card)

And i think you will need this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I have both read and write permission already set in the manifest but it still gives the same error so i cant even get to the drawable part to test it. The word File has a red line under it with the error File cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: tried the following  Drawable myDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), temp);
                 ImageView backgroundView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background);
                 backgroundView.setImageURI(null); 
                 backgroundView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);   but it now says "Drawable cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Error like : _Drawable cannot be resolved to a type_
is because you need import it. Add this statement to top of your Activity class:
`import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;`

Comment: already has that in the imports but still says it cant be resolved

Answer (score 0):

the following Works

```
            Resources res = getResources();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(temp);
            BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);
            View view = findViewById(R.id.background);
            view.setBackgroundDrawable(bd);
```

Mark